# MongoDB: Does the $and operator impact query performance?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have quite complex query in the project. It can potentially (depends on params from user) have a lot of conditions, which I place under `$and` and `$or` operators.

Here is very simplified example:

```
docs.find({name:"shaq", organization: "myorg", url:{$exists:true}})
```

So in the case above documents meeting **all** three conditions will be retrieved. 
Same result can be achieved with this code:

```
docs.find({$and:[
 {name:"shaq"}, 
 {organization:"myorg"}, 
 {url:{$exists:true}}
]})
```

I wonder how that influence the performance. Is it actually the same, or it works slower because of additional operator, or it works faster because according to the [official docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/):

> `$and` operator uses *short-circuit evaluation* meaning that if first
>   expression in list returns `false` mongo will not evaluate the
>   remaining expressions

So question is: Does placing conditions under the `$and` operator influence the performance? If yes, then what is the impact?

P.S.
I tried to investigate the results with mongos `explain()`, but it did not answer my question because my real queries are huge, resulting in the huge report, which is really hard to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

Try investigating the results with a smaller query.

I experimented on one of my databases comparing the two versions and found no difference in the execution plan given a fairly simple query with 3 options.   This is pretty much what I expected as they really should equate to the same query.

I think you will find that the indexes the query ends up using will have a bigger impact on performance than the format of the query.